# I'm adding an image in css file and it's also visible in chrome inspect, but in website it's not visible

Tags: html, css

This is the code

```
.nav-link-apple {
    width: 1.6rem;
    background: 4.4rem;
    background: url(./Logo.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
```

The image I added is visible in inspect at chrome but not visible on webpage. I searched on YouTube etc why my image isn't visible but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: yes its save in the same folder

Comment: Try url(‘./Logo.jpg’ ) try to quote your path name also the name maybe case sensitive and finally make sure it is in the right path

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `height` too. Try this:

```css
.nav-link-apple {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 100px;
  background: 4.4rem;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link-apple"></div>
```